# Find a subset of length K from a set of N numbers (1...N) where k<=N whose XOR value is X

Tags: algorithm, bitwise-xor

Write an algorithm to find a subset of length K {A1, A2 ... , AK} from a set of N numbers (1...N) where K<=N and A1^A2..AK-1^Ak is X (where a^b represents bitwise XOR of a and b). Print the subset in any order. Print -1 if no subset is possible.

Constraints: 1 <= K <= N <= 10^6

e.g

if N=5, K=4, X=5

Output:
1 2 3 5

if N=5, K=5, X=5

Output: -1

I have tried the following solution:

- Find all possible subset of length K
- Check if xor sum of any subset = X

The complexity of the above solution O(C(n, k)) which is not optimal for large N value.
Is there any linear time solution to this problem. Please help.

Comment: Community would be interested in understanding what have you tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: One approach is to find a small subset that XORs to X, and then pad that solution with subsets that XOR to 0. For example, given N=5, K=4, X=5, the small subset is {5}, and the padding is the subset {1,2,3}.

Comment: @user3386109 Would your solution work for N=7, K=6, X=7?

Comment: Yes, the small set is {4,5,6}, and the padding is {1,2,3}

Comment: What's the logic behind selecting {4,5,6} and not {4,3}? There can be multiple such smaller sets.

Comment: Sure, there are seven ways that you can partition the numbers 1..7 into two subsets that XOR to 0. After partitioning the array, there are two questions you need to answer. 1) What's the next step towards finding the solution? 2) Which partition(s) lead to a very simple pattern that can be used for other values of N and K?